# Database Backup Job Failed

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, sql-agent

I have a sql agent job setup for taking full backup every night. Last night the job failed with the following error message.

**Sql Server Error Log Message**

> BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: write failure on backup device
>   'H:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\My_Database_backup_2014_04_28_233008_2135500.bak'.
>   Operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15100).
>
> Error: 3041, Severity: 16, State: 1.

**SqlAgent Job History Log**

> Executed as user: DomainName\sqlagent. Microsoft (R) SQL Server
>   Execute Package Utility  Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit  Copyright
>   (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.    Started: 
>   23:30:01  Progress: 2014-04-28 23:30:06.81     Source:
>   {123123123-F70A-430F-8041-12312312313}  Executing query "DECLARE @Guid
>   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER      EXECUTE msdb..sp...".: 100% complete  End
>   Progress  Error: 2014-04-28 23:30:16.19     Code: 0xC123123
>   Source: Back Up Database (Full) Execute SQL Task     Description:
>   Executing the query "BACKUP DATABASE [My_Database] TO  DISK =
>   N'H:\MSS..." failed with the following error: "Write on
>   "H:\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\MY_Database_backup_2014_04_28_233008_2135500.bak"
>   failed: 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100) 
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.  10 percent processed.  20
>   percent processed.  30 percent processed.  40 percent processed.  50
>   percent processed.  60 percent processed.". Possible failure reasons:
>   Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly,
>   parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
>   End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1). 
>   Started:  23:30:01  Finished: 23:30:16  Elapsed:  14.844 seconds.  The
>   package execution failed.  The step failed.

After doing the research on web mostly posts suggest I do not have enough space on the disks, I have checked the space on my disks I have have atleast 30 plus GB of free space on almost every drive, (disk for .mdf and disk for .ldf files). I have almost 15 gb of free space on my C drive. as One of the posts on web suggested not having enough space on C drive can also cause issues.

Has someelse ever faced the same issue, how you fixed it? what can be the reason for this error and how I can avoid it in the future. Any suggetions pointers in the right direction are most welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Everyone just to let people know if this happens to you, It is some sort of a `Operating System Error` and cannot be regenerated for further investigations. There is no HotFix or Patch available for it as yet.

All I could find on the web was this [`Operating system error 2(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) is not helpful`](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/686192/operating-system-error-2-failed-to-retrieve-text-for-this-error-reason-15105-is-not-helpful).

It is an Active bug logged on [`Microsoft Connect`](https://connect.microsoft.com/) and I hope Microsoft is "Working" on it to fix it :).

Till then just pray that it does'nt happen to you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is this part of the error message: "Operating system error 2".

This translates to file not found.

ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (0x2)
The system cannot find the file specified.

Probably a hadware or device driver problem, causing the lost connection to H: drive.